# OpenGLES vertex shader clarification

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I have a vertex shader written as follows:

```
attribute vec4 position;
varying vec3 colorFactor;

void main()
{
  colorFactor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (position.x * 0.0078125), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;

}
```

and in the code, vertices are submitted and drawn as follows:

```
  glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
  glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, 15*4, vertexSamplingCoordinates);
  glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, inputTextureSize.width * inputTextureSize.height / 16);
```

Variable vertexSamplingCoordinates points to the base address of pixel buffer.

My question is for each vertex, what does is the value of position and how is it computed? I know each component of gl_Position is between -1 & 1 but in each iteration of vertex shader, what is the value of position?

EDIT: Here is the fragment shader as well:

```
   const lowp float scalingFactor = 1.0 / 256.0;
   varying lowp vec3 colorFactor;

   void main()
   {
     gl_FragColor = vec4(colorFactor * scalingFactor , 1.0);
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, it is 64 instead of 60. I corrected the question. Can you tell me what exactly is the value position holds, is it the pixel value at the point or something else?

Comment: This is an extract from sample code in GPUImage by @BradLarson. I am trying to figure out how exactly he computes Histogram for color channels.

Comment: I have posted fragment shader as well. Can you tell me how the program calculates histogram values for red channel?

Comment: Yes, it does that (added it in the code above). Why 1/256.0 is added?

Comment: Still there are some gaps on how it calculates histogram. FYI, this renders to a texture which is 256 pixels wide and 3 pixels in height (one for each R, G, B) as 256x1 textures are not supported on iPhone.

Comment: I checked the code, the stride size is 60 instead of 64, more confusion!